# Mulesoft 4.0 Pass UDT Param to Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

All,

I need to pass to a stored procedure in Mulesoft. The Definition of Oracle Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
  procedure update_snapsheet_task(P_ASSIGNMENT_ID     IN number,
                              P_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS IN varchar2 default null,
                              P_REFERRAL_ID       IN number,
                              P_DOCUMENT_ARRAY    IN p_document_arr,
                              P_USER_ID           IN varchar2,
                              P_ERROR_STATUS      OUT varchar2);
```

where p_document_arr is the UDT param that needs to be passed on in Mulesoft

p_document_arr is defined in oracle as:

```
Type p_documentid_arr IS RECORD(
   document_key   VARCHAR2(4000),
   document_id    NUMBER(10),
   DOWNLOAD_COUNT NUMBER default 0);
Type p_document_arr is table of p_documentid_arr index by binary_integer;
```

How do I pass something in P_DOCUMENT_ARRAY in Mulesoft 4.0?

I tried this link: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-pass-an-array-of-objects-to-a-stored-procedure-in-mule-4

Basically, the link suggest to use

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
fun documentContents(documentRecord) = (
    Db::createStruct("Database_Config", "P_DOCUMENTID_ARR", [
                    documentRecord.document_key,
                    documentRecord.document_id,
                    documentRecord.download_count ])
)
fun documentContentTab(documentArray) = (
    documentArray map ((item, index) ->
        documentContents(item)
    )
)
---   
{
    "p_assignment_id": vars.inputPayload.assignment_id,
    "p_assignment_status": vars.inputPayload.assignment_status,
    "p_referral_id": vars.inputPayload.referral_id,
    "p_document_array": Db::createArray("Database_Config",
        "P_DOCUMENT_ARR",
        documentContentTab(vars.inputPayload.documents default [])),
    "p_user_id": vars.inputPayload.user_id
}
```

For stored procedure call:

```
SQL Query : { CALL cpm.cpm_notification_services.update_snapsheet_task(:p_assignment_id, :p_assignment_status, :p_referral_id, :p_document_array, :p_user_id, :p_error_type) }
```

Also, In global config I put:

```
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config"
    doc:id="22ad9e72-3df1-4d21-bf8a-407d0c97e491">
    <db:data-source-connection dataSourceRef="oraclePoolDataSource" >
        <db:column-types >
            <db:column-type id="-10" typeName="CURSOR" className="oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes" />
            <db:column-type id="2003" typeName="P_DOCUMENT_ARR" />
            <db:column-type id="2002" typeName="P_DOCUMENTID_ARR" />
        </db:column-types>
    </db:data-source-connection>
</db:config>
```

But it did not work. Mulesoft is outputting an error:

```
{
  "status": "Server Error",
  "message": "\"Exception while executing createStruct(\"Database_Config\",\"P_DOCUMENTID_ARR\",[\"abcdes123\", 1, 0]) cause: An error occurred when trying to create JDBC Structure. Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type \"P_DOCUMENTID_ARR\" \nTrace:\n  at callFunction (Unknown)\n  at createStruct (line: -1, column: -1)\n  at documentContents (line: 4, column: 1)\n  at main (line: 11, column: 1), while writing Java.\nTrace:\n  at callFunction (Unknown)\n  at createArray (line: -1, column: -1)\n  at main (line: 19, column: 21)\" evaluating expression:...
...
```

Or from the console logs:

```
Message               : "Exception while executing 

createStruct("Database_Config","P_DOCUMENTID_ARR",["abcdes123", 1, 0]) cause: An error occurred when trying to create JDBC Structure. Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type "P_DOCUMENTID_ARR" 
Trace:
  at callFunction (Unknown)
  at createStruct (line: -1, column: -1)
  at documentContents (line: 4, column: 1)
  at main (line: 11, column: 1), while writing Java.
Trace:
  at callFunction (Unknown)
  at createArray (line: -1, column: -1)
  at main (line: 19, column: 21)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/java
fun documentContents(documentRecord) = (
Db::createStruct("Database_Config", "P_DOCUMENTID_ARR", [
    documentRecord.document_key,
        documentRecord.document_id,
        documentRecord.download_count ])
)
fun documentContentTab(documentArray) = (
documentArray map ((item, index) ->
documentContents(item)
)
)
---
{
"p_assignment_id": vars.inputPayload.assignment_id,
"p_assignment_status": vars.inputPayload.assignment_status,
"p_referral_id": vars.inputPayload.referral_id,
"p_document_array": Db::createArray("Database_Config", 
"P_DOCUMENT_ARR",
documentContentTab(vars.inputPayload.documents default [])),
"p_user_id": vars.inputPayload.user_id
}".
```

Please help.

Comment: It did not work is not very helpful to understand the problem. What there an error? Please provide the details so there is more chance that someone can help you.

Comment: updated the question with more info. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. That error seems to have been formatted by some error handler. Do you have the full raw error from the log?

Comment: Yes, included the error from the console log.

Comment: What Oracle JDBC driver and version is the application using?

Comment: the oracle driver is 12.0.1